# Average of a numpy array returns NaN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an np.array with over 330,000 rows. I simply try to take the average of it and it returns NaN. Even if I try to filter out any potential NaN values in my array (there shouldn't be any anyways), average returns NaN. Am I doing something totally wacky?

My code is here:

```
average(ngma_heat_daily)
Out[70]: nan

average(ngma_heat_daily[ngma_heat_daily != nan])
Out[71]: nan
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> np.nanmean(ngma_heat_daily)
```

This function drops NaN values from your array before taking the mean.

Edit: the reason that `average(ngma_heat_daily[ngma_heat_daily != nan])` doesn't work is because of this:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

according to the IEEE floating-point standard, NaN is not equal to itself! You could do this instead to implement the same idea:

```
>>> average(ngma_heat_daily[~np.isnan(ngma_heat_daily)])
```

`np.isnan`, `np.isinf`, and similar functions are very useful for this type of data masking.

Comment: That worked! Could you explain what the issue is with just taking the average? I have another array of 16k entries (produced from the same original source) that worked fine with the average() method.

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is a function named nanmedian which ignores NaN values. Signature of that function is: `numpy.nanmedian(a, axis=None, out=None, overwrite_input=False, keepdims=<no value>)`